# Scala version error with Spark 2 & ElasticSearch 5.4.2

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-2.0

I'm using Spark 2.2 (build with Scala 2.11.8) to index my data into ElasticSearch 5.4.2.
[image]

ElasticSearch :

[image]

My project spark use this pom.xml :

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run my job, I get this exception :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
>           at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ReflectionUtils$.org$elasticsearch$spark$serialization$ReflectionUtils$$checkCaseClass(ReflectionUtils.scala:42)
>           at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ReflectionUtils$$anonfun$checkCaseClassCache$1.apply(ReflectionUtils.scala:84)
>           at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ReflectionUtils$$anonfun$checkCaseClassCache$1.apply(ReflectionUtils.scala:83)

I know my problem is Scala version (build/run)  ...

Thanks for your help

EDIT BUILD POM :

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <argLine>-J-Xms128m</argLine>
                            <argLine>-J-Xmx512m</argLine>
                            <argLine>-J--XX:MaxPermSize=300m</argLine>
                            <argLine>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</argLine>
                            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>UBER</shadedClassifierName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.databricks:spark-csv_${scala.compact.version}</include>
                                <include>org.apache.commons:commons-csv</include>
                                <include>org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: are you building a fat jar?

Comment: Yes. I edited with my pom build.

Comment: Can you open that zip with unrar/unzip and check whether the mentioned class is available or not?

Comment: In org.elasticsearch.spark.serialisation I got 
> ReflectionUtils$$anonfun$checkCaseClassCache$1.class

class is available

I edited the execption on OP